# Extracting reusable service from object oriented systems

Tags: wcf, web-services, oop, soa, legacy

what's the goal of extracting reusable services from legacy object oriented systems? and what should an organization do for the migration of their systems to soa.. is it a good idea to convert each class to a specific service? or a service should contain different classes? what are the approaches and tools to do this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view your OO system's Public API as a service, just one that is heavily coupled to the implementation technology.  In terms of exposing that service or services to other systems, you can then view this as a simple [protocol bridge](http://www.soapatterns.org/protocol_bridging.php) from your [canonical protocol](http://soapatterns.org/canonical_protocol.php) to your OO system in order to provide a [decoupled interface](http://soapatterns.org/decoupled_contract.php).

In terms of what service or services to expose from you legacy system, be driven by business value. If you are creating a service that some other system might want to use someday, then you are doing it wrong.

Finally in terms of how to structure your services, use the [three layer pattern](http://soapatterns.org/three_layer_inventory.php). For you [entitiy layer services](http://soapatterns.org/entity_abstraction.php), you can decompose based on enitiy type (e.g., separate customers from invoices). For you [process layer services](http://soapatterns.org/process_abstraction.php), you can decompose based on process type (e.g., separate new business processes from procurement processes).